# Accessing LUKS-encrypted exFAT partition with FreeOTFE

Tags: windows-8.1, encryption, arch-linux, luks

My computer is setup with dual boot Windows 8.1 and Arch Linux, with the windows partition encrypted with BitLocker and Arch encrypted with dm-crypt/LUKS. (I would have used Truecrypt, but they are on a GPT drive with a UEFI motherboard.)

The problem is that I have been using an exFAT partition as a shared one that both OS's can access, but I recently encrypted it with dm-crypt/LUKS on Arch with the intention of opening it with FreeOTFE.

However, it gives "Unable to mount volume" when I try to mount it in windows, though it still works in arch.

Comment: Note that FreeOTFE is discontinued. There is a fork in active development called [DoxBox](https://github.com/t-d-k/doxbox).

Answer (score 0):

FreeOTFE does not support GPT. Use [LibreCrypt](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt) instead.